# Ошибка UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Money' referenced before assignment BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Не могу понять как исправить ошибку в последнем блоке при `pricelist.append`

Пример ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 141, in <module>
pricelist = BB_parse(base_url, headers)
line 104, in BB_parse
'Money1': Money,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Money' referenced before assignment
```

Мой код:

```
    for page_book in page_books:
        request = session.get(page_book, headers = headers)
        soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
        container_main = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'content-wrapper'})
        for c1 in container_main:
            try:
                article = c1.find('div', {'class': 'article'}).text.strip().replace("Артикул: ", "")
                name = c1.select('h1')[0].text
                description = c1.find('div', {'class': 'description'}).text.strip()
                available = c1.find('div', {'class': 'avl'}).text.strip()
                Money = c1.find('span', {'class': 'catalog-detail-item-price' }).text.replace("Цена:", "").replace("тг.", "").replace("за шт", "").strip()
                oldprice = c1.find('span', {'class': 'catalog-detail-item-price-old' }).text.replace("Цена:", "").replace("тг.", "").replace("за шт", "").replace(" ", "").strip()
                #economy = c1.find('span', {'class': 'catalog-detail-item-price-percent' }).text.replace("Экономия", "").replace("тг.", "").strip()
                Category1 = c1.find_all('span', {'itemprop': 'title'})[1].text
                Category2 = c1.find_all('span', {'itemprop': 'title'})[2].text
                Category3 = c1.find_all('span', {'itemprop': 'title'})[3].text
                catalog_detail_pictures = c1.find_all('div', {'class': 'catalog-detail-pictures'})
                image1 = c1.find_all('a', {'rel': 'lightbox'})[0]['href']
                image2 = c1.find_all('a', {'rel': 'lightbox'})[1]['href']
                image3 = c1.find_all('a', {'rel': 'lightbox'})[2]['href']
            except:
                pass


            for count, tag in enumerate(soup.find_all(class_='name')):
                try:
                    if tag.text == 'ISBN':
                       code = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Издательство':
                       Publish = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Авторы':
                       Authors = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Серия':
                       Series = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Переплет':
                       Blinding = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Количество страниц':
                       Count_Page = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Ширина':
                       Width = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Высота':
                       Height = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Дата последнего тиража':
                       Date = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text


                except:
                  pass

            pricelist.append({
                     'name': name,
                     'article': article,
                     'Money1': Money,
                     'oldprice': oldprice,
                     'code': code,
                     'Publish': Publish,
                     'Authors': Authors,
                     'Series': Series,
                     'Blinding': Blinding,
                     'Count_Page': Count_Page,
                     'Width': Width,
                     'Height': Height,
                     'Date': Date,
                     'Category1': Category1,
                     'Category2': Category2,
                     'Category3': Category3,
                     'image1': image1,
                     'image2': image2,
                     'image3': image3
                })


        print(len(pricelist))



    else:
        print('ERROR or Done. Status_code = ' + str(request.status_code))

    return pricelist

def files_writer(pricelist):
    with open('Book24.csv', 'w') as file:
        a_lol = csv.writer(file)
        a_lol.writerow(('Наименование', 'Артикул', 'Цена', 'Старая цена', 'Код ISBN', 'Издательство', 'Авторы', 'Серия', 'Переплет', 'Количество страниц', 'Ширина', 'Высота', 'Дата последнего тиража', 'Родительская категория', 'Категория', 'Подкатегория', 'Картикнка_1', 'Картикнка_2', 'Картикнка_3'))
        for RF in pricelist:
            a_lol.writerow((RF['name'], RF['article'], RF['Money1'], RF['oldprice'], RF['code'], RF['Publish'], RF['Authors'], RF['Series'], RF['Blinding'], RF['Count_Page'], RF['Width'], RF['Height'], RF['Date'], RF['Category1'], RF['Category2'], RF['Category3'], RF['image1'], RF['image2'], RF['image3']))


pricelist = BB_parse(base_url, headers)
files_writer(pricelist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде, чем работать с `Money` вам надо ее проинициализировать.

Так как в цикле в конструкции `try-catch` у вас не выполняется инициализации переменной (потому что `try` не сработал), то при `pricelist.append` за циклом питон не знает, что это за переменная

Comment: Сможете пожалуйста подсказать пример, как в данном случае проинициализировать Money?

Comment: До `try-catch` задайте `money` какое-нибудь значение. Но учите, что если не выполняется trycatch, то будет писаться в апенд то, что вы в неё запишите

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!